# A sequence of functions which converges point wise to a function but does not converge in L_2

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on old prelim problems and one asks for a sequence of continuous functions on $(0,1)$ which converges pointwise to a function but does not converge in $L_2$. I have been thinking about this for several hours but have not come up with anything that works. I seem to remember that there is a simple example, but I cannot find reference to it. I was wondering if someone could provide one or more examples of sequences that would work here? A single example would help, but a list of examples would be more useful to understanding whats really going on. Ideally, I'd like to be able to come up with my own examples, but I need first an underlying principle. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f_n=n1_{(0,1/n)}$ has $L^2$ norm $\left(\int_0^{1/n} n^2\,dx \right)^{1/2}=((1/n)\cdot n^2)^{1/2}=\sqrt{n}$.  The sequence converges pointwise to $0$ on $(0,1)$ since, for any $x\in (0,1)$, we have $f_n(x)=0$ whenever $x>1/n$, i.e., whenever $n>1/x$.

Comment: The $f_n$'s were supposed to be continuous.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry I missed that.  The functions I present can be replaced by continuous functions which are $n$ for $x$ between $0$ and a value close to $1/n$ and then descend linearly to $0$, but that makes everything messier.

Answer (score 0):

The continuous functions $f_n(x) = nx^n$ converge to $0$ pointwise on $(0,1),$ but $\int_0^1 f_n^2 \to \infty.$